# http cookies and selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium with firefox.  I am having trouble getting the http_only cookies retrieved from the code.

```
driver.manage().getCookies();
```

brings in regular cookies, but not httponly cookies.  Is there a way to retrieve these cookies?  Or is it really a deadend?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the approach like this:

```java
public void testHttpOnlyCookies() {
    driver.get("https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions");
    Set<Cookie> cookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
    cookies.stream().filter(c -> c.isHttpOnly()).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

in other words each cookie has a property that can be obtained using `isHttpOnly()` method. Using that one you can filter all cookies to either get `httpOnly` or not `httpOnly`.

Comment: are you saying the manage.getCookies() gets everything?  I didnt get everything in that call.  all httponly cookies were missing in what was returned.

Comment: Yest, it gets everything and when I prepared the example I used FireFox like you do.